# How to install sqlite or postgresql on windows 8 for a ruby on rails setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, 64-bit, postgresql-9.3

I've been trying to install a database as part of my ruby on rails setup.
I'm running a 64 bit windows 8, a x64 based machine.
My ruby version is 2.1.3p242, rails version is 4.0.0, sqlite3 version is 3.8.6 and postgresql version is 9.3
I first tried to install sqlite3 by following the steps given in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480381/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-windows) but I get this error

```
`require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid.
```

My database.yml has 'sqlite3' as the value for the adapter key for all three environments.
Next I try to installed postgresql which was installed properly. I fired up the pgadmin3 GUI and started the database server. But when I start the rails server. I get the following error

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.1-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:10:in `re
quire': cannot load such file -- 2.1/pg_ext (LoadError)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems the current version of the gem 'pg' i.e 0.17.1 does not support ruby 2.1

Comment: really? I'm stuck with this too, it seems that PostgreSQL rails and windows are not happy together

Comment: I installed ruby 2.0.0..it seems to work with it..anyway ruby 2.1 is very unstable because a lot of gems were complaining while doing bundle install..use pik to manage different versions, its a great tool

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the pre release of pg.

1. Install

   ```
   gem install pg -v 0.18.0.pre20141117110243 --pre
   ```
2. Add to your Gem file

   ```
   gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.0.pre20141117110243'
   ```
3. Update with Bundle

   ```
   bundle update
   ```

Comment: I'm using 32-bit ruby 2.1.5 & DevKit (because many common gems still have trouble with 64-bit ruby) so I had to make sure: 1) 32-bit PostgreSQL was installed to match the gem and 2) the folder containing pg_config was in my Path. Otherwise, gem install pg failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PostgreSQL you'll need to do 2 things:

1. Install PostgreSQL on Windows using [these instructions](http://www.startprogrammingnowbook.com/book/setup#uid21)
2. Configure your rails project to use PostgreSQL this way:

`rails new todo --database=postgresql`

On the related note, if you want to do web development with Ruby on Rails, I recommend you to install Ruby, Gems, Git, Rails and IDE. All instructions are in the [Start Programming Now book](http://www.startprogrammingnowbook.com/book/setup#cid9)